# Remove duplicates from Ruby arrays and sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have the following array of arrays [date, value]:

```
array = [[12 Mar 2015, 0], [12 Mar 2015, 5], [13 Mar 2015, 0], [14 Mar 2015, 49], [15 Mar 2015, 51], [15 Mar 2015, 10], [16 Mar 2015, 110], [17 Mar 2015, 0], [18 Mar 2015, 31], [19 Mar 2015, 47], [20 Mar 2015, 0], [21 Mar 2015, 0], [22 Mar 2015, 138], [22 Mar 2015, 10], [23 Mar 2015, 0]]
```

You can see that there are arrays with duplicate dates. How would one sum the values while grouping by the dates? This is what I am looking for:

```
array = [[12 Mar 2015, 5], [13 Mar 2015, 0], [14 Mar 2015, 49], [15 Mar 2015, 61],  [16 Mar 2015, 110], [17 Mar 2015, 0], [18 Mar 2015, 31], [19 Mar 2015, 47], [20 Mar 2015, 0], [21 Mar 2015, 0], [22 Mar 2015, 148],  [23 Mar 2015, 0]]
```

Comment: `[12 Mar 2015, 0]`, how do you expect it to work? It should be `["13 Mar 2015", 0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED

Many thanks to @nathanvda, `inject({}) do |hash, [time, index]|` was my mistake. In any case his solution is clearer.

```
array.inject({}) do |hash, item|
  time, index = item.to_a
  hash[time] = hash.fetch(time, 0) + index
  hash
end.to_a
```

Comment: This is not even correct ruby syntax. If I run this it does not work. The second parameter for the block cannot be `[time,index]`. And this is the accepted answer? Weird.

Answer (score 3):

Your array of days should look like

```
array = [["12 Mar 2015", 0], ["12 Mar 2015", 5], ["13 Mar 2015", 0], ["14 Mar 2015", 49], ["15 Mar 2015", 51], ["15 Mar 2015", 10], ["16 Mar 2015", 110], ["17 Mar 2015", 0], ["18 Mar 2015", 31], ["19 Mar 2015", 47], ["20 Mar 2015", 0], ["21 Mar 2015", 0], ["22 Mar 2015", 138], ["22 Mar 2015", 10], ["23 Mar 2015", 0]]

grouped = array.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |result, itm|
  result[itm.first] += itm.last
  result
end.to_a
```